# More elegant way to check whether two nodes have same status on child nodes

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm writing a simple program to create a Binary Tree with Nodes. I don't have a problem with the code, I was just wondering if it was possible to shorten my code to something elegant and nice-looking

Currently I have:

```
//helper function for overloaded ==
//checks to see if both nodes in Binary Trees have the same children nodes
//filled. If not, due to preconditions, they would not be equal

if ((root->left == nullptr && compare->left != nullptr)
    || (root->left != nullptr && compare->left == nullptr)
    || (root->right == nullptr && compare->right != nullptr)
    || (root->right != nullptr && compare->right == nullptr)) 
{
    return false;
}
```

Only other way I can think of is breaking it into multiple `if` statements. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is shorter and, possibly, more easy to read:

```
if ((root->left == nullptr) != (compare->left == nullptr)
    || (root->right == nullptr) != (compare->right == nullptr))
{
    return false
}
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head that's exactly what I was looking for, just couldn't think of it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if (!(!root->left == !compare->left
   && !root->right == !compare->right))
    return false;
```

The general idea is that you can compare the result of two comparisons:

```
(root->left == nullptr) != (compare->left == nullptr)
```

Comment: I don't want to compare whether they're pointing at the same thing, rather that they are structurally the same (like you pointed out in the second code comment). Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the comment above the code. It only checks whether one pointer is exclusively null, but it doesn't check whether they are actually the same. What about this:

```
if (root->left != compare->left || root->right != compare->right) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to check if they're the "same" as in literally pointing at the same thing, I want to check whether both trees are structurally the same (does root have a right node whereas the compare one doesn't - trees cannot be the same). But I appreciate your input